# Why does <main> not define the scope of <header> and <footer>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, semantic-html

While going through the HTML standard's definition for ***[sectioning content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#sectioning-content-2)***, it says that such elements define the scope of `<header>` and `<footer>` and that they can only be `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<nav>` and `<section>`.

Now, this means that if we put `<header>` and/or `<footer>` inside `<main>`, they won't be scoped to that `<main>` element.

My question is: why is this so? **Why can't `<main>` also be considered as a sectioning content element?**

Doesn't it make sense to be putting `<header>` and `<footer>` inside a `<main>` element.

Answer (score 2):

The [usage notes for the `<main>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#usage_notes) state:

> `<main>` doesn't contribute to the document's outline; that is, unlike elements such as [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body), headings such as [h2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), and such, `<main>` doesn't affect the [DOM's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) concept of the structure of the page. It's strictly informative.

The `<main>` element isn't intended to be structural, and doesn't contribute to the document outline. It's solely and strictly meant to demarcate the dominant content within a document. So it makes sense that it doesn't act as sectioning content.

Comment: Admittedly, I had also assumed that `<main>` acted as sectioning content and contributed to the document outline before researching this today.